# Sort dictionary by value of other dictionary in Python

Tags: python

How to sort this **dictionary** by `'votes'` in Python?

```
{
  1 : {
    'votes' : 2,
    'id' : 10
  },
  2 : {
    'votes' : 10,
    'id' : 12
  },
  3 : {
    'votes' : 98,
    'id' : 14
  }
}
```

To results in:

```
{
  3 : {
    'votes' : 98,
    'id' : 14
  },
  2 : {
    'votes' : 10,
    'id' : 12
  },
  1 : {
    'votes' : 2,
    'id' : 10
  }
}
```

Comment: Sigh. Dictionaries are unsorted.

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered -- the two dictionaries in your post are the same.

Comment: Dictionaries do not have an order, so they can't be sorted at all. What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: Theoretically dictionaries do not have order, but when I do a loop on dictionary, the keys are read on order. So, I need a ordered list with key to be quickly acessed. There's another way to do this?

Comment: The real problem is the following: I have a big dictionary with mixed objects of same structure (changing only `'parent_id'`). Then, what I want is group the children of each parent and make a map to be acessed after and show ordered and indented. But before I show this objects (comments), I need sort this parents by 'votes'. Got it? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> od = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(),
                     key=lambda t: t[1]['votes'],
                     reverse=True))
>>> od
OrderedDict([(3, {'votes': 98, 'id': 14}),
             (2, {'votes': 10, 'id': 12}),
             (1, {'votes': 2, 'id': 10})])
```

where `d` is your original dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

Dictionaries are unsorted, if you want to be able to access elements from you dictionary in a specific order you can use an `OrderedDict` as in jcollado's answer, or just sort the list of keys by whatever metric you are interested in, for example:

```
data = {1: {'votes': 2, 'id': 10}, 2: {'votes': 10, 'id': 12}, 3: {'votes': 98, 'id': 14}}
votes_order = sorted(data, key=lambda k: data[k]['votes'], reverse=True)
for key in votes_order:
    print key, ':', data[key]
```

Output:

```
3 : {'votes': 98, 'id': 14}
2 : {'votes': 10, 'id': 12}
1 : {'votes': 2, 'id': 10}
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard dictionaries do not have an order, so sorting them makes no sense. Both those dictionaries are exactly the same.

Perhaps what you really want is a list?

```
aslist = originaldict.values()
aslist.sort(key=lambda item:item['votes'], reverse=True)
```

This will extract the items from your dict as a list and resort the list by `votes`.

Comment: I need a hash for later recover the items directly. But before I need mount and sort the dict to others things.

Comment: Use the dict as a "pool" and sorted lists as indexes. (Items are not copied, so you can have the same leaf dict in multiple data structures.) Dicts *do not have any order*, so if order matters you need to use something else. BTW, list item get/set is O(1) (faster than dict), so you might be better off using lists for everything, even the original dict!

Answer (score 0):

You could also sort the items in the dictionary:

```
print sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['votes'], reverse=True)
```

like Francis' suggestion, but you know the original key for every item.